# How to remove transparency when resizing a window [kubuntu 19.04]

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 19.04, plasma-5, transparency

As shown in

[image]

other windows become transparent when I resize one. How can I remove this effect?

Comment: I cna't recreate this effect in 18.04 LTS - but look in System Settings > Desktop Behaviour > Desktop Effects for the "Translucency" effect. I expect that is where you will be able to control this.

Comment: @JoeP see https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/bxdpia/how_do_you_remove_transparency_when_resizing/. It's possibly an issue in 1**9**.04.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution with help from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/bxdpia/how_do_you_remove_transparency_when_resizing/) reddit post, but the workaround for this bug didn't work out of the box and so I'll post an answer here too.

First of all, the effect is caused by the "sticky window snapping" kwin script. Not usually a problem but apparently a bug prevents users from accessing its configuration gui to remove this effect. So to get the settings back type:

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/kservices5
cp ~/.local/share/kwin/scripts/sticky-window-snapping/metadata.desktop ~/.local/share/kservices5/kwin-script-sticky-window-snapping.desktop
```

The first command creates a folder called *kservices5* into which the second command then copies a file. Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `kwin --replace`.

Then open the settings app (close it if it was previously already open)  and go to the kwin scripts section and tweak the sticky window snapping settings to match your preferences.